# Mapping of String values to Integer for large files

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to map my user ids in text file to unique integer values using java code.
I have a large text file of around 50MB, doing it the traditional way will take me a lot of time
e.g.

```
     3245 4567
      3245 8726
      4567 8363
      4567 7363
      4567 5267 etc
  After mapping I want my output file to look like
     1 2
     1 3
     2 4
     2 5
     2 5
```

Comment: What is the "traditional way" you've tried so far?

Comment: The normal brute force approach...where the code runs in a loop, which takes a lot of time

Comment: Would regex with replace help? edit: Have you tried it?  I've never tested the performance on such a large file before.

Comment: What do you mean the "code runs in a loop"? Of course there will be loops, but what exactly have you tried?

Comment: My loop code runs in o(n^2) time, comparing each unique id with every other

Comment: I want to preserve the order hence cannot sort

Comment: So ... you have a goal to achieve a desired result .. but you don't have an implementation to show us.  Nobody here is being paid consulting fees to develop algorithms for you.  Show us the code you're working on and people will be happy to offer suggestions; but don't come here asking people to develop code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `HashMap<String, Integer>` (see [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) where the integer is a counter incremented every time you encounter a new ID. You will literally have a mapping of ID strings to integers, so it should be very easy to process the text from there. Thus your expected running time is O(n).

Alternatively, you can also try using the hash code given by `String.getHashCode()`. If you have around 10000 IDs there is only a 1% chance of a collision. If you have less the probability decreases dramatically.

Since you've additionally stated that you want to preserve ordering, then the [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is perfect. When you iterate over it, the order is the same as the order of insertion.